# pax-exam (v2.5) - fails to deploy camel-xstream

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, pax-exam

I am trying to understand/get a working example of PAX-EXAM. From my understanding, i need to deploy the bundle i want to test (in this case, boohoo-esb-common) and any bundles that it uses (in this case, camel-xstream).

However, when i try to run the test, pax-exam/felix fails to deploy the xstream feature. Below is the error i get in my console window when doing a: mvn clean install

> ERROR: Bundle com.boohoo.boohoo-esb-common [25] Error starting file:/C:/Users/GARETH~1.HEA/AppData/Local/Temp/1346170773171-0/bundles/com.boohoo.boohoo-esb-common_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.boohoo.boohoo-esb-common [25]: Unable to resolve 25.0: missing requirement [25.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.blueprint)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.boohoo.boohoo-esb-common [25]: Unable to resolve 25.0: missing requirement [25.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.blueprint)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I've attached a simple [example](http://bit.ly/PoXNeI) which should hopefully show what i mean.

Am i going about this in the right way? or am i not getting how to use pax-exam...

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct (you must provision all bundles you bundle-under-test requires), your execution is not :) You are still missing bundles. Apparently your bundle `boohoo-esb-common` requires a [Blueprint Container](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Blueprint).

Comment: Woops! I've fixed that issue now, but am hitting the xstream issue still. [see here](http://bit.ly/OwS0C0)

The error i get is: osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.thoughtworks.xstream))

But if i try to include the xstream bundle, i get a error stating it isnt valid.

Comment: You should post a new question about that.